# Java replacing \n in String

Tags: java, replace

EDIT:
Not a duplicate, atleast not the same problem as the guy in the question linked, he called string.replace(...) without storing the results. I used replace instead of replaceALL which allows the usage of Regular Expressions

I am currently facing a weird problem. I am trying to remove all whitespace from a string. But somehow it doesn't work for me. Here is a screenshot of it function I am using and the results I get from the debugger:

[image]

Here is the function i am using:

```
public static boolean contentCompare(String s1, String s2) {
    String s3 = s1.replace("\\s", "");
    s3 = s3.replace("\\\\n", "");
    s3 = s3.replace("\\n", "");
    return s1.equals(s2);
}
```

When debugging it i get these values for s1 and s3:

`s1: \n\nWLS-Thread-Pool\nWLS-Thread-Pool\n\nClient\nClient\n\nDBS-Conn-Pool\nDBS-Conn-Pool\n\nDBS-Process-Pool\nDBS-Process-Pool\n\nWLS-CPU\nWLS-CPU\n\nDBS-PQ\nDBS-PQ\n\nDBS-CPU\nDBS-CPU\n\nDBS-I/O\nDBS-I/O\n\n\n\n`

`s3: \n\nWLS-Thread-Pool\nWLS-Thread-Pool\n\nClient\nClient\n\nDBS-Conn-Pool\nDBS-Conn-Pool\n\nDBS-Process-Pool\nDBS-Process-Pool\n\nWLS-CPU\nWLS-CPU\n\nDBS-PQ\nDBS-PQ\n\nDBS-CPU\nDBS-CPU\n\nDBS-I/O\nDBS-I/O\n\n\n\n`

Any ideas why the `\n` are not being removed?

Comment: You've noticed that your return statement `return s1.equals(s2);` ignores `s3`?

Comment: Uhh my question is not a duplicate of that one, the other guys issue was that he didn't know that replace doesn't change the string itself but returns the result. my problem was way dumber :-P

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use

```
s3.replaceAll("\n","");
```

instead of

```
s3.replace("\n","");
```

Comment: Replace is also fine: "Replaces each substring of this string that matches the literal target sequence with the specified literal replacement sequence."

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence, java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: Since `\n` is just a single character, it is fine to use `#replace`. Don't get confused about that `"All"`. It doesn't mean, that this will replace *all* occurrences (other does this as well), it just mean, that this method can replace more than a single String. `#replaceAll` allows the usage of regular expression, `#replace` does not.

Comment: This fixed the other problem i had, my first replace(\s) doesn't actually do anything. with using replaceAll("\s", "") it properly solves my problem

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
s3 = s3.replace("\n", "");
```

Comment: God damnit, now i feel stupid :-) This works. Do i somehow delete my question now/mark it as solved? i am new to posting on so

Comment: @SimonEismann Just mark the response as accepted

Comment: it says i still need to wait 10 minutes to accept it :-(

Answer (score 1):

Try with below code

```
s3= s3.replaceAll("\\s+","")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)
```

Replaces each substring of this string that matches the literal target sequence with the specified literal replacement sequence.

you need to replace`\n` by "" i.e. blank

```
s3 = s3.replace("\n", "");
```